# tigervnc vncviewer could not open some system applications

Tags: x11, gnome, vnc, x11vnc, vncviewer

The computer that I am trying to connect to using vncviewer is a Ubuntu 18.04 system with [dash-to-panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/) gnome extension.

When I used the [first .vnc/xstartup](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8NXV2jRC6n/) , I only got black screen once connected.

When I used the [second .vnc/xstartup](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/52Nngq3z9g/) , I got a [nautilus file manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utsec.png) once connected and I could open pdf using evince by double-clicking on the pdf file itself. BUT **I cannot open gedit by double-clicking on the text file itself as well as open terminal using right click menu**. Why ?

[image]

I got the following journalctl log when I issued *ssh destination_computer_username@destination_computer_ip_addr "DISPLAY=:2 nohup gnome-terminal"* on my source computer terminal

```
Dec 20 14:06:13 UbuntuHW15 dbus-daemon[4137]: [session uid=1000 pid=4137] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.352' (uid=1000 pid=13704
Dec 20 14:06:13 UbuntuHW15 systemd[4111]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
Dec 20 14:06:13 UbuntuHW15 gnome-terminal-server[13707]: Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Dec 20 14:06:13 UbuntuHW15 gnome-terminal-server[13707]: Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:
Dec 20 14:06:13 UbuntuHW15 systemd[4111]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=10/n/a
Dec 20 14:06:13 UbuntuHW15 systemd[4111]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 20 14:06:13 UbuntuHW15 systemd[4111]: Failed to start GNOME Terminal Server.
```

**First .vnc/xstartup**

```
#!/bin/sh

unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
OS=`uname -s`
if [ $OS = 'Linux' ]; then
  case "$WINDOWMANAGER" in
    *gnome*)
      if [ -e /etc/SuSE-release ]; then
        PATH=$PATH:/opt/gnome/bin
        export PATH
      fi
      ;;
  esac
fi
if [ -x /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc ]; then
  exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
fi
if [ -f /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc ]; then
  exec sh /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
fi
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
twm &

gnome-wm&
metacity&
```

**Second .vnc/xstartup**

```
# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
#unset SESSION_MANAGER
#exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &

gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
```

Comment: What do you want to happen?

Comment: @MichaelProkopec I cannot edit text files using gedit !!!!!!  Do you understand  ? the gedit won't open even I double-click on the text file. Same applies to gnome-terminal.  Strangely, I can open pdf using evince though

Comment: You might want to look into why gnome-panel, gnome-settings, metacity and nautilus are listed at the bottom of the one that is close to working. You might try adding gedit and gnome-terminal or just use the whole gnome-session. Keep calm and carry on...

Comment: @MichaelProkopec adding gnome-session & prior to gnome-panel &  does not solve the issue

Comment: Interesting... What is the computer you are connecting from running?

Comment: @MichaelProkopec Does the computer running vncviewer ip_address_of_destination_computer:5902 matter in this case ? I do not think so. The destination computer still have the wrong .vnc/xstartup file

Comment: Where did that last comment come from? I am not sure it was for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87314/discussion-between-michael-prokopec-and-kevin998x).